# get first char of each string in a list

Tags: list, powershell, foreach-object

I am trying to get the first char of each string in a List. The list contains:

```
hehee_one
hrhr_one
test_two
```

I am using a foreach-object to loop the list

```
ForEach-Object {($jsonRules.name[0])}
```

But what this does is getting only the first element, which makes sense. and if i do this:

```
ForEach-Object {($jsonRules.name[0][0])}
```

I only get the first char of the first element but not the rest..

so please help me..
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

**Provide the strings you want the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet to operate on *via the pipeline***, which allows you to **refer to each via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)** (the following uses an array literal as input for brevity):

```
PS> 'tom', 'dick', 'harry' | ForEach-Object { $_[0] }
t
d
h
```

Alternatively, for values already in memory, use the [`.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) array *method* for better performance:

```
('tom', 'dick', 'harry').ForEach({ $_[0] })
```

The [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement* provides the best performance:

```
foreach ($str in ('tom', 'dick', 'harry')) { $str[0] }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `ForEach-Object { ... }` - without pipeline input - is essentially the same as executing `...` directly.

  - Thus, expressed in terms of the sample input above:

    - You executed:

      ```
      ForEach-Object { ('tom', 'dick', 'harry')[0][0] }
      ```
    - which is the same as:

      ```
       ('tom', 'dick', 'harry')[0][0]
      ```
    - which therefore extracts the *first* element from the input array (the first `[0]`) and then applies the second `[0]` to *that string only*, and therefore only yields `'t'`.
- In other words: **use of `ForEach-Object` only makes sense *with input from the pipeline*.**